# How to derive the density of Gaussian Copula?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, copula

I have a question regarding Gaussian copulas:

The multivariate Gaussian copula is defined as, 
$$
C(u_1,\dots,u_n;\Sigma) = \Phi_{\Sigma}(\Phi^{-1}(u_1),\dots,\Phi^{-1}(u_n)),
$$
where $\Phi_{\Sigma}$ is a multivariate $n$-dimensional normal distribution with correlation matrix $\Sigma$ and $\Phi$ is the standard univariate cumulative distribution function. How can we show that the corresponding density
is:
\begin{align}
  c(u_1,\dots,u_n;\Sigma) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mbox{det} \Sigma}}\exp
        \begin{pmatrix} - \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}}
          \begin{bmatrix}
           \Phi^{-1}(u_1) \\           
           \vdots \\
           \Phi^{-1}(u_n)
          \end{bmatrix}^{T} [\Sigma^{-1} - I ]
          \begin{bmatrix}
           \Phi^{-1}(u_1) \\
           \vdots \\
           \Phi^{-1}(u_n)
         \end{bmatrix}
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: which source is that multivariate formula from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x=[\Phi^{-1}(u_1),\ldots,\Phi^{-1}(u_n)]^{\top}$. Then
\begin{align}
c(u_1,\ldots,u_n;\Sigma)&=\frac{\partial^nC(u_1,.\ldots,u_n;\Sigma)}{\partial u_1\cdots\partial u_n}=\frac{\Phi(x;0,\Sigma)}{\prod_{i=1}^n \phi(x_i)} \\
&=(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}x\right)\times\prod_{i=1}^n (2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(\frac{1}{2}x_i^2\right) \\
&=|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}x+\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}x\right) \\
&=|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}(\Sigma^{-1}-I)x\right).
\end{align}

Comment: which source is that formula  for the density of the multivariate copula from?