# Derivation of bivariate Gaussian copula density

Tags: exponential-function, correlation, gaussian, bivariate-distributions, copula

The **multivariate Gaussian copula density**, derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606749/how-to-derive-the-density-of-gaussian-copula), is

$$c(u_1,\ldots,u_n;\Sigma)=|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}(\Sigma^{-1}-I)x\right)$$
where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix, and  $x=[\Phi^{-1}(u_1),\ldots,\Phi^{-1}(u_n)]^{\top}$.

The **bivariate Gaussian copula density**, based on the pair-wise correlation coefficient $\rho$, is
$$
c\left(u_{1}, u_{2} ; \rho\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}} \exp \left\{-\frac{\rho^{2}\left(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}\right)-2 \rho x_{1} x_{2}}{2\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)}\right\}
$$

What is the derivation of the second formula from the first?

Comment: My initial guess would have been $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ but the numerator in the exponential doesn't seem to match up...

Comment: How about $\Sigma=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma^{2} & \rho \sigma^{2} \\
\rho \sigma^{2} & \sigma^{2}
\end{array}\right]$?

Comment: Also, $$\frac{\det(\Sigma_{0})}{\det(\Sigma_{1})} = \frac{\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}-\sigma_{12}^{2} }{ \sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}} = 1-\frac{\sigma_{12}^{2}}{\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}} = 1-\rho^{2}$$ where $\Sigma_{0}$ is the covariance matrix of the multivariate Gaussian in question and $\Sigma_{1}$ is the covariance matrix of the marginal product measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with standard normal marginals

$$\Sigma=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \rho  \\ \rho  & 1 \end{array}\right],\,\, |\Sigma| = 1 - \rho^2$$

and

$$\Sigma^{-1}= \frac{1}{1- \rho^2}\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -\rho \\ -\rho  & 1 \end{array}\right], \,\, \Sigma^{-1}-I= \frac{1}{1- \rho^2}\left[\begin{array}{cc} \rho^2 & -\rho \\ -\rho  & \rho^2 \end{array}\right]$$

Hence,

$$- \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\top}(\Sigma^{-1}-I)\mathbf{x} = \frac{-1}{2(1- \rho^2)}\left[\begin{array}{cc} x_1 & x_2 \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} \rho^2 & -\rho \\ -\rho  & \rho^2 \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} x_1 \\ x_2  \end{array}\right] \\= \frac{-1}{2(1- \rho^2)}\left[\begin{array}{cc} x_1 & x_2 \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} \rho^2x_1  -\rho x_2 \\ -\rho x_1  + \rho^2 x_2 \end{array}\right] \\= -\frac{\rho^2 (x_1^2 +x_2^2)- 2\rho x_1 x_2 }{2(1-\rho^2)},$$

and, thus,

$$|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\top}(\Sigma^{-1}-I)\mathbf{x}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- \rho^2}} \exp \left\{-\frac{\rho^2 (x_1^2 +x_2^2)- 2\rho x_1 x_2 }{2(1-\rho^2)} \right\}$$

Comment: why does your $\Sigma$ look like a correlation matrix? I thought it was supposed to be a covariance matrix

Comment: As per the starting point of your linked answer $\Phi$ is a standard univariate normal distribution function (variance is $1$) and $\Sigma$ is the correlation matrix which is also  a covariance matrix when the marginals have unit variance. Furthermore the desired form of $c(u_1,u_2;\rho)$ does not depend on $\sigma_i \neq 1$.